c++ genera .exe.recipe en vez de .exe
estaba haciendo un proyecto de antlr y estaba tratando de debugar un proyecto en c++.
#include <iostream>

#include "antlr4-runtime.h"
#include "calcLexer.h"
#include "calcParser.h"
#include "calcBaseListener.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace antlr4;

class TreeShapeListener : public calcBaseListener {
public:
    virtual void enterProgram(calcParser::ProgramContext* ctx) override {
        cout << "enterProgram\n";
    }
    virtual void exitProgram(calcParser::ProgramContext* ctx) override { 
        cout << "exitProgram\n";
    }

    virtual void enterStat(calcParser::StatContext* ctx) override { 
        cout << "enterStat\n";
    }
    virtual void exitStat(calcParser::StatContext* ctx) override {
        cout << "exitStat\n";
    }

    virtual void enterExpr(calcParser::ExprContext* ctx) override {
        cout << "enterExpr\n";
    }
    virtual void exitExpr(calcParser::ExprContext* ctx) override { 
        cout << "exitExpr\n";
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open(argv[1]);
    ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    calcLexer lexer(&input);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    calcParser parser(&tokens);

    tree::ParseTree* tree = parser.program();
    TreeShapeListener listener;
    tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(&listener, tree);

    return 0;
}

ya he generado los archivo correspondientes de antlr y tambien construi los archivops dll.

en linea de comandos con el siguiente comando:
xcopy /y /d "C:\Users\joaqu\OneDrive\Documentos\Compiler\antlr4-cpp-runtime-4.13.2-source\runtime\bin\vs-2022\x64\Debug DLL\antlr4-runtime.dll" "$(OutDir)"

en eventos de compilacion.
tambien aplique los directorios de inclusión adicionales

y esto compila satisfactoriamente con 2 exitos y 0 errores

pero aqui viene el error, que cuando se compila en visual studio 2022 no se genera un ".exe" en vez de esto se genera un "exe.recipe"


No conosco visual studio, ¿no tiene un parámetro como gcc: gcc -o comida.caliente comida.c ? -o es abreviación de --output

@DABL03 no creo que el problema esté en los parametros, según se ve parece compilar bien ._?

@Christian Haa, ya. Solo ojeé la pregunta, no me detuve a leerla bien, pense que mas bien queria esa salida :)

Por favor la salida de la consola colócala como texto, esa imagen no enseña la salida completa...

El .exe.recipe es un archivo de texto, puedes abrirlo con un editor y verás contenido organizado en formato xml. Este contenido son metadatos que usa Visual Studio para generar el ejecutable.
Creo que tu .exe se está generando en otra ruta, en el exe.recipe indicará cuál es esa ruta. De no ser así comprueba tu configuración de proyecto:

Propiedades de proyecto → Propiedades de configuración → Directorio de salida
